# Efficient way to find words from a wordlist table that are contained in input text

Tags: mysql

I've got a wordlist table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wordlist` (
    `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
    `word` varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

With lots (thousands) of entries like that:

```
| 1 | foo |
| 2 | bar |
| 3 | xyz |
```

And I have an input text `Hello xyz, test me barhaha` - this should get `xyz` and `bar` from the table. The text can be a few kilobytes long.

The naive solution is:

```
SET @text = 'Hello xyz, test me barhaha';
SELECT * FROM `wordlist` WHERE @text LIKE CONCAT('%', `word`, '%');
```

It doesn't use indexes, neither `LOCATE()/INSTR()` will do, and performs a full table scan. Is there a way to speed up this kind of search, ideally utilizing indexes?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the full text capabilities in MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Really, this was my second thought: put text into a temporary table with a full-text index and then run a query against it. Thanks.